# Firebase saves data as List and sometimes as Map object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving data with key as numeric values, where keys are questions attempted by user. It may be continuous if user has attempted all the questions eg. keys may be 0,1,2,3... this is saved by Firebase as Array (as in image)

[image: list as saved by Firebase]

JSON is

```
"parthgupta48@gmail,com": {
  "attemptedQuestions": [
    {
      "answer": "533",
      "status": "wrong",
      "submissionTime": 1487796702453
    },
    {
      "answer": "9",
      "score": 10,
      "status": "correct",
      "submissionTime": 1487878744867
    },
    {
      "answer": "4",
      "status": "wrong",
      "submissionTime": 1487956858227
    },
    {
      "answer": "3",
      "status": "wrong",
      "submissionTime": 1488056247303
    },
    null,
    {
      "answer": "25",
      "score": 16,
      "status": "correct",
      "submissionTime": 1488212417465
    },
    {
      "answer": "3",
      "status": "wrong",
      "submissionTime": 1488380348815
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "answer": "50",
      "score": 11,
      "status": "correct",
      "submissionTime": 1488648738615
    }
  ],
```

When keys are discontinuous eg 0,9,15... this happen when when user has attempted only certain questions then Firebase saves this as map (as in image)

[image: map as saved by firebase]

JSON is

```
"priyanshu96,goyal@gmail,com" : {
      "attemptedQuestions" : {
        "0" : {
          "answer" : "667",
          "status" : "wrong",
          "submissionTime" : 1487773682189
        },
        "10" : {
          "answer" : "50",
          "submissionTime" : 1488646361162
        }
      },
```

This is my code I used to retrieve data in Android.

```
try {
       mCurrentUser = child.getValue(UserObject.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {

       Utils.makeToast("Some Error Occurred ",LoginActivity.this);

   }
```

**userObject class**

```
public class UserObject implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String uid;
private String email;
private String photoUrl;
private String contact;//bekaar
private long credits;
public Map<String,AttemptedByUserObject> attemptedQuestions;

public void setAttemptedQuestions(Map<String, AttemptedByUserObject> attemptedQuestions) {
    this.attemptedQuestions = attemptedQuestions;
}

public Map<String, AttemptedByUserObject> getAttemptedQuestions() {
    return attemptedQuestions;
}

public long getCredits() {
    return credits;
}

public void setCredits(long credits) {
    this.credits = credits;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}}
```

But problem is `attemptedQuestions` needs to be list when data is saves as list and it need to be `Map` when data is saved as `Map`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The Firebase data model is not well suited to storing arrays (or Java `List` objects). See [this blog post explaining the behavior you get](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Instead of storing a `List`, follow the [Firebase documentation's approach for storing collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). This will indeed store it as a map, which is the correct approach precisely because it prevents the problems that you have now when you manipulate the items.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for reply ,I don't want to save my data as list but I want keys to be numeric as they denote question number .Is there any way I can get data in android irrespective of way it is stored (i.e either map or array)

Comment: If your items have a numeric key, prefix it with a fixed string to get around the array coercion. E.g. `"question10"`.

Comment: This solution can be used in future (when I save new data ).Is there something I can do on saved data

Answer (score 2):

When the information is saved with consecutive keys starting from Zero (I.e. 0, 1, 2, etc.) you will get back a list, in my case I was starting from One so for some reason it got me back a list starting with a null element. When keys are discontinuous a Map will be returned. After understanding this I ended up patching it with a type check, and because of the null in the list cases I remove the first element.

```
when (it) {
    is Map<*, *> -> doSomething(it.values.toList() as List<HashMap<String, Any>>)
    is List<*> -> doSomething((it.subList(1,it.size)) as List<HashMap<String, Any>>)
    is Any -> return
}
```

In the example doSomething only takes `List<Hashmap<String, Any>>` arguments, but the variable `it` can be either a Map or a List.