# How to filter list of data in list in java with sql or nested dynamic condition

Tags: java, json, lambda, filter, predicate

How to filter data dynamically using java, Assume we have data (list of map / json array without pojo mapping).

```javascript
[
  {
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Internal",
    "status": "Closed"
  },
  {
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "External",
    "status": "Closed"
  },
  {
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Internal",
    "status": "Open"
  },
  {
    "id": "1004",
    "type": "Internal",
    "status": "Open"
  }
]
```

Now we need out put filtered data as `id > 1001 and  ( type: 'External' or status: 'Open" )`

```javascript
 [ 
  {
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "External",
    "status": "Closed"
  },
  {
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Internal",
    "status": "Open"
  },
  {
    "id": "1004",
    "type": "Internal",
    "status": "Open"
  } 
]
```

Any Suggestions how to achieve this ?

Comment: I most say I am confused, do you want to extract the data from the raw json? a database of from a list of objects?  What have you tried and where are you having problems?

Comment: @S_R have posted an answer see if that is what u r asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use javascript ability to resolve condition. We can use Java ScriptEngineManager to run javascript expression :
Expression can be `type = 'Internal' AND status ='Open'`

```html
    private String getResult(String expression) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            return engine.eval(expression).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON path , below are few `JSONPath` queries I have posted as an sample example

P.S :- Ur **"Id"** should be of type Integer for operation > or `<`

Code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonData = "[\r\n" + 
            "  {\r\n" + 
            "    \"id\": 1001,\r\n" + 
            "    \"type\": \"Internal\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"status\": \"Closed\"\r\n" + 
            "  },\r\n" + 
            "  {\r\n" + 
            "    \"id\": 1002,\r\n" + 
            "    \"type\": \"External\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"status\": \"Closed\"\r\n" + 
            "  },\r\n" + 
            "  {\r\n" + 
            "    \"id\": 1003,\r\n" + 
            "    \"type\": \"Internal\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"status\": \"Open\"\r\n" + 
            "  },\r\n" + 
            "  {\r\n" + 
            "    \"id\": 1004,\r\n" + 
            "    \"type\": \"Internal\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"status\": \"Open\"\r\n" + 
            "  }\r\n" + 
            "]";
    
    String filterId = "$.[?(@.id > 1001)]"; //For Id > 1001
    String filterType =  "$.[?(@.type in ['External'])]"; //for External type
    String filterTypeAndId =  "$.[?((@.id > 1001) && (@.type in ['Internal']))]"; //for External type with Id > 1001
    String filterTypeAndId2 =  "$.[?((@.id > 1001) && (@.type in ['Internal', 'External']))]"; //for External type with Id > 1001
    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonData);
    System.out.println(documentContext.read(filterId).toString());
    System.out.println(documentContext.read(filterType).toString());
    System.out.println(documentContext.read(filterTypeAndId).toString());
    System.out.println(documentContext.read(filterTypeAndId2).toString());
}
```

**results are :-**

```
[{"id":1002,"type":"External","status":"Closed"},{"id":1003,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"},{"id":1004,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"}]

[{"id":1002,"type":"External","status":"Closed"}]

[{"id":1003,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"},{"id":1004,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"}]

[{"id":1002,"type":"External","status":"Closed"},{"id":1003,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"},{"id":1004,"type":"Internal","status":"Open"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the following approach :-

1. Convert json to string
2. Construct JSONArray >> JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(converted_json_String)
3. pull out jsonArrayObject from JsonArray and construct a list
4. Use Collections.sort method and deploy your comparision logic in it on the JSON keys
   and construct your sorted json.

Answer (score -1):

try this code, I am assuming you have a list of objects.

```
List<YourCLass> filteredList = list
                    .stream()
                    .filter(obj -> obj.getId() > 1001 && (obj.getStatus().equals("Open") || obj.getType().equals("External")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

filteredList have the list of objects you are expecting, using Object mapper you can get it as json format.

```
String filteredObjJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValuesAsString(filteredList);
```

add this dependency in pom.xml or download the lib and add it to your libraries

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Need to achieve this without POJO mapping.

Comment: it is possible, try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841661/parse-json-with-gson-without-pojo). this is having that solution.